# Excel: is it possible to show a cells contents in a text box within text?

Tags: excel

I have a textbox that I need to keep updated with the contents of a cell. At the moment I update it manually.
I know you can use a textbox to display a cells contents by referring to the cell in the formula bar of the textbox, but I would like to know if its possible to display a cells contents in part of the text?

For example...

If I have a cell that contains the number 1.23 and a text box that contains the text "The cell shows 1.23" how can I get the number in the textbox to show the contents of the cell instead of the "1.23" as flat text.
...like the equivalent of Concatenate("The cell shows ",A1) but in a textbox?

Is there a way to do this without using VBA?

UPDATE -I decided to go the other way and put the 'Concatenate' formula in a cell on a hidden sheet. The box then points at the cell on the hidden sheet.
I would like to know if there is an answer to my original question though.